# How to get to apple iphone discussion forums?

Tags: iphone

I logged into my account and is reaching this page.
http://developer.apple.com/devforums/
After that when i click login and give the details, it redirects to the same page.
Where can I see the discussions and post questions?

I know its a simple question but dont know what I am missing here.

Comment: This is a question about Apple's developer forums website, and is not a specific programming question.  I recommend contacting their support if you are having problems.

Comment: reset your Safari cache. i have had the same issue with re-directs

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be registered with the iPhone Developer Program to access those forums.

Comment: Ya, i have a registered account and I am logging in. But why is it still redirecting to the same page??

Comment: Logging in takes me to https://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone, does that URL work for you?

Comment: When i use this URL, its again redirecting to the same page.